# LuaXML does not handle whitespaces after '='

Tags: lua, luaxml

I am using LuaXML version 1.7.4, and it cannot handle whitespaces after the equal sign in attribute value assignments:

```
<g>
<t m= "50"/>
</g>
```

generates garbage data. If the space after 'm=' is removed, everything works fine.

Known issue?

Comment: You would probably be better off asking the LuaXML developers about this. People on StackOverflow are not likely to know the answer, or to be able to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be a bug, or it is just unnecessary. It is not common practise to leave no whitespace between equals in markup languages (read anything HTML) so it may have not been implemented.

Either way, it is not a major issue and this should be taken to the devs if you would like it to be changed.